# A model of computation vs an abstract machine

Tags: terminology, computation-models

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability#Formal_models_of_computation) says

   > **A model of computation** is a formal description of a particular type of computational process. The description often takes the form
   >   of an **abstract machine** that is meant to perform the task at
   >   hand.

   What other forms can a model of computation take than an abstract
   machine?
2. What are the difference and relation between [a model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation)
   and [an abstract machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_machine)? I thought that they were the same, until I saw the the quote above.

Comment: Abstract machines are one example of a model of computation. The lambda calculus is a model of computation but not an abstract machine.

Comment: Thanks. Why is lambda calculus  not an abstract machine? What category  (i.e. a peer of abstract machines) does it belong to then?

Comment: I guess you'd call it a "calculus". Another example of such a calculus might be the pi calculus which is designed to model concurrent computation. Neither of these are abstract machines because they don't attempt to model hardware. The Turing machine or the SECD machine are examples of abstract machines.

Comment: Thanks. What do they (calculi) attempt to model instead of hardware? Do calculi model software?

Comment: I suppose the difference is that calculi are _denotational_ in nature - they model computation mathematically and have meaning outside of their implementation - and abstract machines are _operational_ in nature - they model computation as a series of steps to be carried out by some imaginary hardware, and this tie their meaning to the behaviour of said hardware.

Comment: By denotational and operational, do you use them for modifying "model of computation" (i.e. denotational/operational model of computation)? I am interested in looking up for more. (I heard of  denotational/operational only when they are used for modifying "semantics of programming languages", i.e. denotational/operational semantics of programming languages)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31219/discussion-between-benjamin-hodgson-and-tim).

Comment: Mod note: I [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25247475#25247475) Benjamin Hodgson to add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

An abstract machine typically defines instructions with opcodes and operands. A Warren abstract machine, a java virtual machine, a Turing machine.  A programming model defines operations at a higher level, and could be independently supported by a number of different machines.  For example the actor programming  model says that an actor can send a message, create a new actor, and define internal state for its next message to be handled.  This is said without defining specific opcodes and operands, though one could envision an abstract machine that supported that.